# dispatcherTimer not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this event listener using WPF and C#. What I do is just changing the color of certain buttons. I change the color of one and then I move on to the next one. The problem is that I'm trying to make it interactive and change the color using different times depending on the value of a slider that I have in my XAML. The problem is that when I restart the game more than 3 times the timer starts ignoring the values of the slider and the colors of the buttons change with a pattern that doesnt match whats on the slider.
Any suggestions?

```
private void Restart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SnackBoxes = 2;
        theBabies[0] = new Baby();
        theBabies[1] = new Baby();
        theBabies[2] = new Baby();
        theBabies[3] = new Baby();
        theBabies[4] = new Baby();
        theBabies[5] = new Baby();
        theBabies[6] = new Baby();
        theBabies[7] = new Baby();
        theBabies[8] = new Baby();
        theBabies[9] = new Baby();
        resetBabies();
        dispatcherTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
        int timeSlider = (int)(11 - theSlider.Value);
        MessageBox.Show(""+timeSlider);
        dispatcherTimer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeSlider);
        dispatcherTimer1.Tick += delegate
        {
            int nextBabyRed = nextBabyToTurnRed(theBabies);

            switch (nextBabyRed)
            {
                case 0:
                    Baby1.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[0].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Baby2.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[1].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Baby3.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[2].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Baby4.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[3].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Baby5.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[4].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Baby6.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[5].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Baby7.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[6].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Baby8.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[7].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Baby9.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[8].Happy = false;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Baby10.Background = Brushes.Red;
                    theBabies[9].Happy = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }

            //dispatcherTimer1.Stop();
        };
        dispatcherTimer1.Start();
        //MessageBox.Show(""+theSlider.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create a new timer ever time, just change the interval.

So rather than:

```
    dispatcherTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    int timeSlider = (int)(11 - theSlider.Value);
    MessageBox.Show(""+timeSlider);
    dispatcherTimer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeSlider);
    dispatcherTimer1.Tick += delegate
```

Have `dispatchTimer` declared at an outer scope, and created but stopped. Move the delegate out of the `Click` handler into its own method:

```
private void DispatchTimerClick(...)
{
   // ...
}
```

And hook that event handler up when the timer is originally created by the form.

Then, your click handler becomes:

```
    int timeSlider = (int)(11 - theSlider.Value);
    MessageBox.Show(""+timeSlider);
    dispatcherTimer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeSlider);
    dispatcherTimer1.Start();
```

The `Start` isn't really necessary here unless you've stopped it somehow (or if it was never started).

Answer (score 1):

"dispatcherTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer();"

Is where the problem lies I think. You're creating new timers but the old ones would still be running.

Try stopping the old timers before creating new ones.